# Website Attached to App

Tags: ios, objective-c, web, uiwebview

How do I attach a website to an app in Xcode using the UIWebView?  The only chunk of code in the assistant editor is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface XYZAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator    
*persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end
```

What would be the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://conecode.com/news/2011/05/ios-tutorial-creating-a-web-view-uiwebview/ Google is the answer to this question.

Comment: I got to step 17 but holding control and dragging is not linking the two parts.  Nothing lights up or gets highlighted.

Comment: Figured it out, just had to use source code at the bottom of the page.